# jquery array and string

Tags: jquery, arrays, join

I have this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.a_mod_t', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var data_d = 'id=' + id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: data_d,
                cache: false,
                url: "php/show_dec.php",
                success: function (html) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(html);
                    $.each(obj, function (index, element) {
                        var id_trattamento = element.id_trattamento; // trattamento, id_tariffa, tip_dente, denti(txt)
                        var id_tariffa = element.id_tariffa;
                        var tip_dente = element.tip_dente;
                        var denti = element.denti;
                        var array = new Array();
                        var array2 = new Array();
                        var var_a = "#";
                        array = denti.split(',');
                        var arrayLength = array.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                            // put the # inside the array 
                            alert(array2[i]);
                            //Do something
                        }
                        alert(id_trattamento);
                        alert(id_tariffa);
                        alert(tip_dente);
                        alert(array[0]);
                    }); // fine .each
                }, // fine success
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                    console.dir(xhr);
                } // fine error
            }); // fine ajax
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this code I get a string text and then I split it and put it into an array. Everything is fine but I need to do another thing and I don't know how..
this array contains the splitted text so for example I have array[0] that contains the text "61". 61 is also the id of a checkbox that I need to change with jquery. but to do so I need to put a "#" in my array before every text. I need to know how I can obtain this -> array[0] = #61 ..
or if there is a way to join the # symbols during the jquery command, something like:

```
$ '#' . ('array[0]').css(..);
```

Comment: Use `$('#' + array[0]).css(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend it to the selector:

```
$('#' + array[0]).css(..);
```

Note: *Numeric only IDs* are only valid HTML for HTML 5 and should be avoided.